# Is comprehension possible here?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
l=[('soccer',11),('tennis',2),('chess',2),('xanadu',None)]
```

Supposed we define a function as below:

```
def func(x):
    if type(x) is int:
       return x*2
    else:
       return None
```

I need this function to be applied on element [1] of every tuple ,and the result return as a dictionary with element [0] as the key.

Is this possible as a comprehension on list 'l'?
Just to make the thing a bit interesting - I need to include ONLY those results where func(x) returns a int.

Expected output:

```
{'soccer':22,'tennis':4,'chess':4}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, with tuple expansion its fairly easy

```
dict([(x, func(y)) for x, y in l])
```

or to do the whole thing at once (2.7+)

```
{x: func(y) for x, y in l if isinstance(func(y), int)}
```

if func is expensive and you dont want to calculate it twice you could *(but if its something simple like your example I wouldn't bother)*

```
{key: value for key, value in ((x, func(y)) for x, y in l) if isinstance(value, int)}
```

or for python 2.6.x

```
dict((key, value) for key, value in ((x, func(y)) for x, y in l) if isinstance(value, int))
```

as Nisan.H was commenting this has become a bit unclear so maybe for clarity break it into 2 lines

```
func_l = ((x, func(y)) for x, y in l)
result = dict((key, value) for key, value in func_l if isinstance(value, int))
```

Comment: or even better assuming func is really as simple as described above `(x,x*2) for x,y in l`

Comment: A slight twist added to the post

Comment: It's worth noting that the dict comprehension is only available in 2.7.x and 3.x: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: @IUnknown added to answer for your twist

Comment: `{x:v for x,v in ((x,(lambda v: v*2 if isinstance(v,int) else None)(y)) for x,y in l)}` (or using `func` instead of the lambda), otherwise you'd be evaluating `func(y)` twice per pair

Comment: Wouldnt this be calling func(y) twice for each x,y?

Comment: @IUnknown yes, the question is how expensive is your func vs. how expensive is going through the list twice (added another option in the answer)

Comment: It's also possible to just evaluate type of `y` as a precluding condition: `{x:func(y) for x,y in l if isinstance(y,int)}`  (in this case, you can use the original `func(y): return x*2`)

Comment: @Nisan.H yes, assuming that `func` returns `int` if `y` is `int`?  I was assuming that the real `func` was really more complicated then the example

Comment: True - the real function is much more complicated.Evaluating the input to the function is not an option--{key: value for key, value in [(x, func(y)) for x, y in l] if isinstance(value, int)}  seems the closest choice but I am getting a syntax error in this?

Comment: @cmd fair enough. Although, I would probably still seek to separate precluding filters from the processing where possible (e.g. use `test(y)` and `func(y)`) to make things more obvious. The nested comprehension works well enough for compound function case, but it's also slightly less obvious as to what it does when reading the code.

Comment: @IUnknown that same line works fine for me with the example list (on Python 2.7.4)

Comment: @IUnknown works for me too, what version of python are you using and what exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: >>> l=[(0,1),(2,3),(8,7),(2,None)]
>>> def func(x):
...     if type(x) is int:
...         return x*2
...     else:
...         return None
...         
>>> r={key:value for key,value in [(x, func(y)) for x, y in l] if isinstance(value, int)}
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 1
    r={key:value for key,value in [(x, func(y)) for x, y in l] if isinstance(value, int)}
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @IUnknown is it possible you are not using python 2.7 or later?  if so use list comprehension to the dict constructor `dict([...])` instead of dictionary comprehension `{...}`

Comment: Am on 2.6.5. However, r=dict([key:value for key,value in [(x, func(y)) for x, y in l] if isinstance(value, int)])
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @IUnknown copy new line I put in the answer, the `:` operator only works for dict comprehension, you should have a tuples to pass to the dict constructor

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l=[('soccer',11),('tennis',2),('chess',2)]
>>> def func(x):
        return x*2
... 
>>> dict((a, func(b)) for a,b in l)
{'tennis': 4, 'soccer': 22, 'chess': 4}
```

using dict comprehension:

```
>>> { a : func(b) for a,b in l}
{'tennis': 4, 'soccer': 22, 'chess': 4}
```

**Update:**

```
def func(x):
    return x*2

lis = [('soccer',11),('tennis',2),('chess',2),('xanadu',None)]

#do type checking here
print { a : func(b) for a,b in lis if isinstance(b, (int,float))}

#for py2.6 or earlier
print dict( (a, func(b)) for a,b in lis if isinstance(b, (int,float)))
```

**output:**

```
{'tennis': 4, 'soccer': 22, 'chess': 4}
```

Comment: It is actually the return of the function that needs to be checked on ,rather than the input.The function I have in here is just an illustration  - the actual is much more complex

Comment: @IUnknown Then use a simple for-loop loop, it is going to be more readable. As zen say : "Readability counts".